# PHP trader_stochrsi returns false

Tags: php, pecl, trading

I am trying to pass variables to the PHP pecl extension's 'trader' project's trader_stochrsi() function.

here is my use example :

```
$stochrsi = trader_stochrsi(array(5.5), 14, 3, 3);
var_dump($stochrsi);
```

I get the following read-out in the var_dump :

```
bool(false)
```

--Any thoughts as to why this may be happening?

Thanks,

GS

Comment: It maybe because you don't have enough data values. You are telling it to crank out a StochRSI array based on only 1 array value over 14 periods. Supply it with at least 14 values in the array.

Comment: duhhh--makes logical sense--thanks--will try

Comment: It worked--thank you so, so much :)

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying 14 intervals the function must have to be able to give an RSI value, but your array only contains one interval i.e. 5.5.

You should put 15 items in your array. It will use the first 14 to calculate a value and output it for 16th interval.

Answer (score 0):

For me it works after 19 elements:

```
array (size=19)
  0 => float 1.298E-5
  1 => float 1.246E-5
  2 => float 1.129E-5
  3 => float 1.091E-5
  4 => float 1.015E-5
  5 => float 1.075E-5
  6 => float 1.056E-5
  7 => float 1.046E-5
  8 => float 1.07E-5
  9 => float 1.046E-5
  10 => float 1.113E-5
  11 => float 1.163E-5
  12 => float 1.216E-5
  13 => float 1.253E-5
  14 => float 1.295E-5
  15 => float 1.356E-5
  16 => float 1.285E-5
  17 => float 1.43E-5
  18 => float 1.426E-5
->>> 
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      18 => float 100
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      18 => float 100
```